# update multi tables in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I'm trying to know what's the wrong with this function , which i need to update only one field in table or the all fields in multi assocatied tables . 
The multi update is working fine , but when i going to update only the first column it's not working fine with me

```
public function edit($id) {
    $contractor = $this->Contractors->get($id);

     $associated = ['ContractorsAttachments' ];
    // Used to get the all attachments associated with Contractors 
     $ContractorsAttachments = $this->Contractors->ContractorsAttachments->find()->where(['contractor_id' => $id])->all();
    if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
      $contractor = $this->Contractors->patchEntity($contractor, $this->request->data );

       if ($this->Contractors->save($contractor)) {

            $this->Flash->success(__('The Contractors has been saved.'));

            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('The Contractors could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }
    $this->set(compact('contractor','ContractorsAttachments'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['contractor']);
    $this->render('add');
    }
```

Comment: What is the use of `$associated = ['ContractorsAttachments' ]`

Answer (score 0):

You can get associated model data using [contain](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#retrieving-associated-data).

Use [Saving With Associations](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#saving-with-associations)

After the tweaks your code will be like this

```
     $contractor = $this->Contractors->get($id, ['contain'=>'ContractorsAttachments']);

     if ($this->request->is(['patch', 'post', 'put'])) {
       $contractor = $this->Contractors->patchEntity($contractor, $this->request->data );

       if ($this->Contractors->save($contractor,['associated' => ['ContractorsAttachments']])) {

            $this->Flash->success(__('The Contractors has been saved.'));

            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('The Contractors could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
    }
```

Also verify that you **Contractors** Model has the association defined like this

```
        $this->hasMany('ContractorsAttachments', [
            'foreignKey' => 'contractor_id'
        ]);
```

Hope this will help :)

Comment: Thank you for your comment , the problem was something alse , it's back to this line at my form
 <?= $this->Form->create($contractor, ['type' => 'file']) ?>
Can you know how to make the file not required ?